# Role of jogging/running in bodybuilding regime

Tags: running, bodybuilding

People have different opinions about running,jogging even walking. There are somethings I want myself to be cleared about which I looked out a lot but couldn't satisfy myself.

1. What time or days per week one should go for running with respect to evening workout schedule and for how long?
2. Does too much running effects knees in the long run and do i need to be track specific like grass or roadside?
3. Which exercise should be coordinated with workout after running?
4. A silly one rather- Is milk enough to cope up with running or extra supplements are required to prevent knee wearing and tearing?

Comment: You should split up your questions into several, instead of asking them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

1. Cardio directly detracts from weight-lifting regime.  It's generally recommended to do cardio after a workout or, even better yet, on your non-lifting days.  [This link](http://www.burnthefatinnercircle.com/members/Concurrent_Strength_And_Aerobic_Training.cfm) has some info.
2. Running on hard surfaces regularly is very bad for your joints as the repetitive impact of the concrete is damaging over time.  [Source](http://saveyourself.ca/articles/running.php)
3. Running incorporates the following muscle groups:
   [The quadriceps femoris, hamstring, gluteus maximus, iliopsoas, calf muscle](http://www.spryfeet.com/2010/04/05/muscles-used-when-running/)

It's probably not news to anyone that you've basically got the entire leg in use when running, so any leg workout done after running follows the idea of a pre-exhaustion workout.  Check this [link](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/zaino11.htm) for ideas related to pre-exhaustion workouts.

1. Regular exercise supplements would likely suffice.  The damage to your joints will likely be from repeated impact on a hard surface, not from lack of nutrition.